# Docker volume-mounting breaks when GitLab CI Pipeline has multiple jobs

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a docker container that is instantiated by my GitLab CI pipeline script like this:

```
docker run -dt -p 8080:80 -v $PWD:/var/www/html --name ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}_${CI_JOB_ID} runner_image
```

The idea is that the contents of my GitLab project are mounted into my container's `/var/www/html`.

If I make the container manually, no problem at all, it works as it should. The container's `/var/www/html` directory contains my project files as I want it to.

If the container is made through GitLab CI's pipeline, though, the container's `/var/www/html` will be empty. Not only that, but it'll then appear empty on the container host (my runner) as well, until I `cd` out and back in the folder, where it'll once again contain my project.

I'm not really understanding what's happening: doesn't GitLab just execute commands on my runner? How can the *same* command have two different results when it's being executed by the same user in the same directory?

**EDIT**: After messing around on my part, it turns out that the volume mounting breaks when the Pipeline is split into multiple jobs.
I can prove this by performing a `docker exec`in the first job and the second one just after that:

```
$ docker exec pipeline_runner ls -la /var/www/html
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 4  997  995  68 Dec  2 16:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  33 Nov 22 15:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 5  997  995 117 Dec  2 16:12 .git
-rw-rw-r--. 1  997  995 737 Dec  2 16:12 .gitlab-ci.yml
drwxrwxr-x. 4  997  995  83 Dec  2 16:12 GCI
-rw-rw-r--. 1  997  995 724 Dec  2 16:12 index.php
```

Second job in the pipeline:

```
$ docker exec pipeline_runner ls -la /var/www/html
total 0
```

I still have no idea *why* this happens, or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you show an example of how your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks? You can tell GitLab CI to not clone or fetch your project by using the `GIT_STRATEGY` flag. You can also test to print `$PWD` in your GitLab jobs, to see that you have the same folder for all of your jobs.

Comment: @MrBerta thanks, I managed to fix it by setting the `GIT_STRATEGY` flag and did test that `$PWD` printed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting the `GIT STRATEGY` for every job that isn't the first:

```
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
        GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
```